# How to disable HyperThreading on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, hyper-threading, macbook-pro-retina

Unlike my old Windows Boxes and Linux Boxes, I do not have access of something similar to a BIOS on my MacBook Pro.

I want to disable Intel i7's HyperThreading (so 4 cores look like 4 cores and don't try to simulate extra ones).

There are solutions for disable HT via developer tools temporarily, but I need something to do it permanently (one that does not reset on reboots).

This is for a MacBook Pro 15" Retina.

Comment: Does the last entry in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2421202?start=0&tstart=0) apply to your case?

Comment: Well, does it or does it not ?

Comment: Nothing worked.

Answer (score 3):

Download and install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). It includes a Processor.prefPane (not sure where it's located exactly) that allows you to disable hyperthreading.

[image]

With Xcode installed, you can also disable hyperthreading using the following terminal command:

```
hwprefs cpu_ht=false
```

I don't believe this setting is retained after restarting your Mac, so you might want to create an AppleScript to run that command on startup.

Comment: This method is disabled on sleep as well, thats why I asked a permanent method.

Comment: These no longer work on Yosemite: the hwprefs command is gone and the Processor.prefPane panel no longer loads.

Answer (score 2):

Any luck with the following? Requires a reboot to take.

```
$ sudo nvram SMT=0
```

Might be something you can put in boot-args as well but I couldn't find it.

```
$ sudo nvram boot-args=""
```

Ref: [Technical Q&A QA1141 Disabling Processor Cores on a Multi-Core System](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1141/_index.html)

Comment: Resets on restart. Already tried this.

Comment: It shouldn't reset if you put it in the boot-args, @Sid . You must have skipped that step.