# See if Mac OS X has enabled hyperthreading?

Tags: mac, terminal, hyper-threading

There is a way of disabling hyperthreading on Mac OS X: [How to disable HyperThreading on Mac OS X Lion?](https://superuser.com/questions/467950/how-to-disable-hyperthreading-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Is there a Terminal command of seeing whether Mac OS X has hyperthreading enabled?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by disabling Hyperthreading?

Comment: I'm not trying to disable HT. I'm just seeing if it is enabled or not. I linked the question because it could be relevant. But Google searches about a terminal command turned up nothing direct.

Comment: Apple does not provide an actual method to disable Hyperthreading. Unless you used those tools described in the other question, then its enabled, and those tools can also help verify if its enabled. **If your processor supports Hyperthreading then its enabled, by default, and can only be disabled until the system is rebooted.**

Answer (score 21):

Compare the result of:

```
$ sysctl hw.physicalcpu hw.logicalcpu
hw.physicalcpu: 4
hw.logicalcpu: 8
```

`hw.logicalcpu > hw.physicalcpu` so hyper threading is enabled